# Zero "sphere" volume of finite surface area

Tags: integration, geometry

We consider spheres in contact to ensure slope continuity for large continuous $z$ as height of sphere stack. When $h<2R$ we have by direct integration
$(z,0,h):$

$$ A =2 \pi R \cdot h;\quad Vol= \pi h^2 ( 3 R-h)/3 ;$$

Cap volume evaluated classically as $ \pi \int_{-R}^{-R+h}(R^2-z^2)dz$

The graphs for area and volume are smooth continuous when plotted. Area is proportional to $h$ upto chosen point for multiple spheres when reckoned from a center point on sphere with vertical tangent. That is in order.But the volume vanishes unexpectedly at $h=3R$ when area result is correct.

Is an interpretation possible to explain the anomaly for the volume expression? Is another better expression for volume of sphere cap possible that holds in the extended $h$ domain as well?

We could in hindsight write the volume as

$$ H =(h \,mod\, 2R),\,Vol = \frac{\pi H^2}{3}(3R-H) + [\frac{h}{2R}] \frac43 \pi R^3 $$

but then why was it not necessary for area formula?

EDIT1:

Outside $|z|>R $ in complex range  of sphere stack $ r^2+z^2= R^2 $ at $(r,z)=(\sqrt3 R i,2 R) $ we have $(Area,Vol)= (6 \pi R^2,0)$

Volume and Area are plotted as function distance from cap vertex.Yellow region is classical and outside it is the region being discussed.

[image: Vol Sph Caps]

[image: Graph Zero Cap Volume]

The volume as a function of $z$ is given by

$$ Vol(z)=\pi(z+R)^2 (2 R-z)/3, \quad dV/dz= \pi r^2= \pi (R^2-z^2). $$

[Zero Sphere Cap Volume at three radii depth](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20pi%20h%5E2%20(3-h)%2F3,(h,0,3))

Comment: There is no such thing as a "polar cap three radii deep".

Comment: Usually, $0 \leq h \leq 2r$. How do you interpret $h>2r$ in general?

Comment: @Henning Makholm. I know, There exist" touching polar caps three radii deep" of surface area $= 6 \pi R^2$

Comment: I would say that "the volume vanishes unexpectedly" is not a statement about mathematics, but about your reaction to it. I don't think that a mathematical explanation can really address that. Hence I believe that this is not a mathematics question.

Comment: Please allow me to add: Area is increasing linearly both by expectation and it is in fact confirmed by computation. Volume is expected to increase in a wavy fashion, increasing with $z$ to the right but not decrease that way and fall to zero !! I had supposed  integration (tag) familiarity would be adequate to appreciate the anomaly, but I could be wrong. In any case  please feel free to suggest any additions and I would incorporate your indication in improving the post.

Comment: #ekkilop We can interpret $h>2R$ as $z$ distance along axis of symmetry for a stack of contacting spheres stack from cap vertex

Answer (score 0):

Another expression for the volume is $$V= \frac{\pi h}{6}(3  a^2 + h^2),$$
where $a$ is the radius of the base of the polar cap. From this, it is clear that the volume is always positive.

The formula you provide is obtained by substituting $$a = \sqrt{h(2r-h)},$$
and this makes sense over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $0 \leq h \leq 2r$.

If you put $h=3r$ then you obtain a complex value for $a$ (namely, $a = i \sqrt{3} r$), such that $3a^2+h^2=0$.

So you are computing the "volume of a polar cap with purely imaginary radius", and there is no interpretation of this in terms of real numbers.

Comment: @ Francesco Polizi *By that same token* why is the  area $ A= \pi(a^2+h^2) $ real  for imaginary $a?$

Comment: I do not think this is a well-posed question. Consider a cube whose edge has length $r$: the area is $6r^2$ and the volume is $r^3$. The area is real also for purely imaginary length, whereas the volume is not, however I do not see any explanation of this fact in terms of geometry over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As mentioned in the question graph (of function)  of areas/volumes are smooth/continuous compared to more discontinuous surface normals in a cube.